# React Native Build Error Execution failed for task ':react-native-get-sms-android:verifyReleaseResources'

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, gradle

I get a problem to build react native after install 'react-native-get-sms-android', you can find here https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-get-sms-android, I don't know why, I try to look for similar error but fail all.

This is the complete error :

```
> Task :app:processReleaseGoogleServices
Parsing json file: D:\Project\React Native\myProject\android\app\google-services.json

error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored not found.
error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored not found.
C:\Users\frank\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\226ef6010c3c969192062affc53f6ce6\res\values-v26\values-v26.xml:9:5-12:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.

C:\Users\frank\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\226ef6010c3c969192062affc53f6ce6\res\values-v26\values-v26.xml:13:5-16:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.

C:\Users\frank\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\226ef6010c3c969192062affc53f6ce6\res\values-v26\values-v26.xml:17:5-93: AAPT: error: style attribute 'android:attr/keyboardNavigationCluster' not found.

C:\Users\frank\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\226ef6010c3c969192062affc53f6ce6\res\values\values.xml:251:5-69: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontStyle not found.

C:\Users\frank\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\226ef6010c3c969192062affc53f6ce6\res\values\values.xml:251:5-69: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/font not found.

C:\Users\frank\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-27.1.1.aar\226ef6010c3c969192062affc53f6ce6\res\values\values.xml:251:5-69: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontWeight not found.

error: failed linking references.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-get-sms-android:verifyReleaseResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 54s
203 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 199 up-to-date
```

Please anyone help me to solve this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to update your `android build tools version`.
The following worked for me.
In `android/build.gradle` change `ext` to look like this:

```
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "28.0.0"
    minSdkVersion = ... // your min SDK
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    targetSdkVersion = ...// your target SDK
    supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
}
```

and put this at the end of your file:

```
subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "28.0.0"
            }
        }
    }
    afterEvaluate {
        project -> if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 28
                buildToolsVersion '28.0.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In `android/app/build.gradle` change this: `"com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1"` to this: `"com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0"`

Answer (score 6):

**Reason for the error:**

You have installed  *react-native-get-sms-android* as a dependency, And the reason for this error is that the configurations of your `android/app/build.gradle` and   `node_modules/react-native-get-sms-android/android/build.gradle` mismatch.

**Solution**

1. Navigate to `node_modules/react-native-get-sms-android/android/build.gradle`
2. Edit and keep the `compileSdkVersion` `buildToolsVersion` `minSdkVersion` 
   `targetSdkVersion` same as you have in `android/app/build.gradle`
3. Sync the project again.
4. Run `./gradlew assembleRelease` from the terminal.